# Usar expresiones en los ejes de un gráfico GGPLOT2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Buenas tardes,
Mi problema es el siguiente deseo mostrar en un gráfico hecho en R. Quiero introducir expresiones en el Eje de la X de tal forma que se vean así X<sub>1</sub>,X<sub>2</sub>,etc. Teóricamente si podría ponerlo en las categorías usando *expression("X"[2])*. Pero no funciona.
Este es mi planteamiento ahora mismo:

```
X<-c(expression("X"[1],expression("X"[2])
Y<-c(1,2)
Prueba<- data.frame(Y,X)
ggplot(Prueba, aes(x = factor(X,levels = c(expression("X"[1]),expression("X"[2])), y = Y)+geom_point()
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Buenas DePerez. Bienvenido. Puedes explicar por que tu planteamiento no funciona y qué esperas que te cree? Toda informacion relevante es mejor.

Comment: Perdón pero es la primera vez que pregunto algo y he usado HTML puro <pre> y no lo mostraba. Muchisimas gracias de antemano y perdón por mi torpeza

Comment: No te preocupes por la torpeza. Todos fuimos nuevos. Pero recuerda darte una vuelta por el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y por el [centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio ^^

Answer (score 1):

Me autorespondo el truco para que funcione es agregar al plot con cualquier nombre sin expression y posteriormente agregarlo al plot

```
X<-c("X1","X2")
Y<-c(1,2)
Prueba<- data.frame(Y,X)
ggplot(Prueba, aes(x = factor(X,levels = c("X1","X2"), y = Y)+geom_point()
scale_x_discrete(labels = c(
    "X1"   = expression("X"[1]),
    "X2"   = expression("X"[2])))
```

Después de muchos días me acabo de dar cuenta perdón